# R shiny: renderDataTable just not working for me (Cannot read property 'bFilter' of null)

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

If I run the basic example provided in the tutorial, I obtain a blank page. Then if I right-click on the page, and use Inspect Element, I can see the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bFilter' of null

Is there anything I should fix on my side, or is this a bug ? I can't use dataTables in any of my applications due to this...

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/advice, this would be very much appreciated.

Cheers

ps1: the code I use is

```
runApp(list(
ui = basicPage(
h2('The mtcars data'),
dataTableOutput('mytable')
),
server = function(input, output) {
output$mytable = renderDataTable({
mtcars
})
}
))
```

ps2 : I have attached a print screen
[image]

Comment: What is your browser? and your Shiny version?

Comment: Maybe provide the output of `sessionInfo()`. This code works for me in Firefox on Win7 x64, R 3.0.2, shiny 0.8.0

Comment: It's Shiny 0.8.0.99, and R 3.0.2. The browser is a recent version of Google Chrome. The output of sessionInfo() is

Comment: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.8.0.99

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6  caTools_1.16  digest_0.6.4  httpuv_1.2.2  Rcpp_0.11.0   RJSONIO_1.0-3 tools_3.0.2  
[8] xtable_1.7-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You happen to be using a development version that is more than 2 weeks old. Please install the [current development version](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny) on Github. This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/commit/bdeb6734d8667c6b7dd14589020be6adedba1b85) there.